# Google Chrome Kiosk screen does not maximize

Tags: google-chrome, x11, kiosk

I have set up a Chrome Kiosk using a custom session in X to run Google Chrome.

It generally runs pretty well except except for a screen size issue.

I have a "chrome.desktop" session file saved in /usr/share/xsessions with the following contents.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Chrome
Comment=This session logs you into Google Chrome
Exec=/usr/share/xsessions/chromeKiosk.sh
Icon=
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
```

There is also a chromeKiosk.sh file that is used to execute Chrome. It is also in /usr/share/xsessions. The contents are as follows.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do google-chrome http://news.bbc.co.uk --kiosk --start-maximized --disable-restore-background-contents --login-screen-size="1024,768" --disable-translate --disable-new-tab-first-run --enable-vertical-tabs; sleep 5s; done
```

The problem that I am having is that Google Chrome (or Firefox, or Opera. I have tried various apps), will not maximise to the entire 1024x768 display. It seems to be leaving approximately 1 centimetre of space on the right hand side of the display (I can see the desktop), and also some space at the bottom of the screen.

I have tried this on at least 2 different computers. One had a higher resolution screen. It left an even bigger gap.

It is as if the application that it being run thinks the screen is smaller than it actually is.

Does anybody have any idea what is going on? I am going nuts with this problem.

Here is an image so you can see the border

[Google Chrome Kiosk Xsession with odd border](https://picasaweb.google.com/112306928350201874916/ChromeIssueOnUbuntu1204#)

That image is from a screen with a 1280 width.

Comment: I have only tested this on Ubuntu 12.04, so I don't know if it is specific to that version.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why Chrome is doing this, but if you have a look at:

```
/home/{kiosk_user}/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences
```

-- you will see `browser.window_placement` and you should see a difference of about 20 pixels between bottom and `work_area_bottom`, and right and `work_area_right`.

I edited the values to be the full extents of the display size, and saved Preferences, then chown'd then to `root:root` and chmod'd them to `644` so that Chrome (running as the `kiosk_user`) cannot modify the settings.

I restarted the `kiosk_user` session and tada, Chrome was running full full screen.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: But this would make it specific to the device, you cannot create a generic mass manufactured solution.

Comment: See question http://askubuntu.com/questions/184610/custom-session-window-does-not-capture-full-screen-area-by-default-12-04

Answer (score 1):

You are just about to done it... see my codes:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Chrome
Comment=This session logs you into Google Chrome
google-chrome --start-maximized --kiosk http://google.com
Icon=
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
```

now you need to edit Chrome configuration for user
open location: `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/`
and then open `Preferences`.
Search for `"browser": {` and modify followings:

```
   "browser": {
      "check_default_browser": false,
      "clear_lso_data_enabled": true,
      "custom_chrome_frame": true,
      "pepper_flash_settings_enabled": true,
      "window_placement": {
         "bottom": 803,
         "left": 1,
         "maximized": false,
         "right": 1366,
         "top": 35,
         "work_area_bottom": 768,
         "work_area_left": 0,
         "work_area_right": 1366,
         "work_area_top": 37
      },
```

In my PC I've 1366x768 please adjust as you need.
(you may also add this file in /etc/skel location, this will solve the problem while creating new user you don't need to re-config)

Comment: Sorry to say that, you cant escape or log-out from Chrome kiosk mode then you need to do a simple tricks: 
`ALT+CTRL+F1` then login and now type `sudo gdm restart` or `sudo lightdm restart`.
I'm still looking for code to **RUN TERMIANAL CODE** from **BROWSER** I found something like `apt:` for firefox, it opens ubuntu software center with specific system call.